# C# WebMatrix Formatting Error when querying a table with getdate() column

Tags: c#, webmatrix

When someone Searches on my site, a record is created in the `tbl_search` table. The Database decides what the timestamp is by having `getdate()` as the data binding.

**I am trying to get all the data from this table:**

```
@{
  WebMartix.Data.Database DB = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(MyConString)
  var data = DB.Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_search"); // <<<<<< error occurrs here <<<<<<
  foreach (var d in data){
    @d.phrase
  }
}
```

The error is: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

However, the help window in VS has a Troubleshooting tip that says:

> When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

- It works if I change the table to one that doesn't have a getdate() data binding.
- It works when I run the same query on SQL Management Studio.
- I put the query inside a stored procedure, and it had the same results: worked in SQL mgmt studio, but not on the website.

*I did tons more research, but decided for brevity's sake not to show it, especialy since I stumbled across the solution towards the end of writing the question.*

Answer (score 0):

### The ASTERISK (*) in the query was causing the error.

I replaced it with `phrase, timestamp` and it worked:

```
@{
  WebMartix.Data.Database DB = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(MyConString)
  var data = DB.Query("SELECT phrase, timestamp FROM tbl_search");
  foreach (var d in data){
    @d.phrase
  }
}
```

---

*I had been working on this question for a while when I found the solution through trial and error. I found no documentation online about this WebMatrix... [bug] maybe? So I decided to post anyway in hopes that the next person can find it easier, and perhaps someone with more expertise can explain why the asterisk didn't work in the query, but only when the table had a getdate()-generated column.*

Comment: You can definitely use a SELECT * so the trouble is in the database some sort of way.  Since you solved it, i won't ask that you provide some of database definitions.